# Intellij doesnt recognise symbol

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, path, resources

My intellij can't recognise path to images and other files but when i use ctlr+left mb it finds file or image without problem. Im working with other ppl and we share it on github and only i have this problem. When i run application web pages are completely fine but when im trying to just view html file it doesnt recognise css and images. I tried creating project again, clearing cache and reinstalling ide. Photo shows files in project
[how files are structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beDHs.png)

EDIT:
Im trying to view html file clicking [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mwro.png) and that is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyP6B.png). Css and images are missing even though path seems to be correct. Problem occures on my computer. Program works on my teammate pc

Comment: `when im trying to just view html file it doesnt recognise css and images.` The problem is not clear. Please elaborate what exactly you are doing and the problem you get.

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited post hope its understandable now

Comment: Are you using application server to deploy and run the app? Then, you must open the url of the **application that was deployed to server**. But you are probably opening the url of the [built-in IDE web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_preview_output).